# Reusing controllers in different web sites with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a content management for a kind of Enterprises, lets say for example, pets shops.

Thats my projects structure:

PetShopModel

PetShopControllers

PetShopWeb1

PetShopWeb2

PetShopWeb3

The structure is that since each client would have different specifications.

Its that a good choice? or there are better solutions?

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0):

PetShowWeb1, PetShopWeb2, PetShopWeb3?... That doesn't look like a good structure to me at all. I think you need to re-think your model. Use properties instead of defining completely new classes.

Comment: The model is not changing, and the controllers arer'nt neither, what changes is the views only.